# How to hide Excel window from a user

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Is there a way to hide Excel windows from a user - to prevent acidental closing it.

Comment: If I accidentally close a spreadsheet, I just open it again.  Why will this not work?

Comment: My guess, the OP want to prevent accidently closing an Excel instance which has some vba scripts running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OLE automation to control Excel, there is an Application.Visible property that should allow you to hide the window.  I can't recall (offhad) whether this is totally hidden or just minimized.  If you're in VBA, though, I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: VBA is the same. Application.visible = false will hide Excel until scripts are done, then show again with Application.visible = true.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose is and how you intend to use but Application.Visible property can be useful. Alternatively you can add a warning message on Workbook_BeforeClose event

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not MsgBox("Do you want to really close this workbook?", vbOKCancel) Then
       Workbook_BeforeClose = False
    End If 
End Sub
```

Hope this helps... If you could be more elaborate then probably you will have exact solution.