# starting a userform without excel in the background

Tags: vba, userform

I have this vba code where it has a userform. 
Now I would like to start the userform; where the people can't see the Worksheets.

I have added this in my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
Application.Visible = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True  End Sub
```

Then in the "ThisWorkbook; I have added this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Application.Visible = False ' only for final version 
    UserForm1.Show
    'enter code here
End Sub
```

The thing is when I upload this .xlsm to a website, and when you open it; it does not start the userform right away. It somehow goes to an error. If you have an excel open.

Not sure how to protect the file, without having the endusers altering the file
Any ideas?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2099013/8112776) shows how to hide the Excel window, but the userform is not a separate window.  However you could hide Excel's title bar etc, and resize the Excel window to the same dimensions as  the userform, so it *appears* that it's in a separate window.

Comment: If users have their security settings set up correctly, then opening a workbook from a website will disable macros in the workbook until they explicity enable them for that workbook.  Have you taken this case into consideration in what you want to show/hide?

Comment: @ashleedawg: Thanks for the link. the issue now is when a user opens the .xlsm file it freezes the other existing excel files they have; somehow it got stuck. If I am working on a document and wanted to open this .xlsm file; then it returned an error. So I tried ending excel from the task manager then it works fine. So strange. Another thing as well, If I hide the worksheet where I have the reference to in the vba code, it will also returned an error that it is not found. So I have to somehow display the Worksheets and anyone can see it..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

In "ThisWorkbook" under "Open" add:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm2.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

This will hide Excel and execute UserForm2.

BTW: To end your program add this code (e.g. to one of your Userform Buttons):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

It will close Excel.

Comment: Thank you; will try this. My issue now somehow when the user opens the .xlsm file it freezes the excel file if they have it opened in a background. Should I delete my code and replace it with the one you've suggested?